# Send a message from Dialog box (mean-stack site) to the task pane

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ms-office, mean-stack, office-js

I am trying to use [Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) of Office addin.

I can successfully open a Dialog box from my task pane by:

```
$scope.openDialog = function () {
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://localhost:3000/home',
        function (asyncResult) {
            dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
        });
}
```

My Dialog box is a `mean-stack` site. I have added `<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>` in the `index.html`. And I tried to use `Office.context.ui.messageParent(true);`, it shows an error in console:[image]

And I see in the doc that I don't understand quite well:

> The Office JavaScript library is loaded in the page. (Like any page
>   that uses the Office JavaScript library, script for the page must
>   assign a method to the Office.initialize property, although it can be
>   an empty method. For details, see Initializing your add-in.)

I also tried to add `Office.initialize = function () { };` in `index.html`, the error is still there, and `processMessage` of the task pane does not seem to receive anything.

So is there anything special I should do to my `mean-stack` site so that it could use `messagePerent`?

Comment: It just a idea, try to add https://localhost:3000 into manifest file. <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain> domain goes here </AppDomain>
  </AppDomains> There are limitations what you can open in this dialog as a first page. All the pages in appDomain section are trusted by your addin.

Comment: Does 'https://localhost:3000/home' open index.html? You need to load Office in the page that is opened by 'https://localhost:3000/home' and you need to assign a function Office.initialize in script for that same page. If you're doing all that, then try putting some code in the function you assign to Office.initialize so you can see if it runs.

Comment: Yes, `localhost:3000/home` opens `index.html`. So as long as there is `Office.initialize` and the code in it runs, it will be ok? Should I insert something related to angluarjs into it?

Comment: I just meant as a troubleshooting step, put something in the Office.initialize, like a console.log, so we can see whether Office.initialize runs. It is (almost) the last thing that Office does when it initializes itself. If Office.initialize doesn't run, then Office is not fully initializing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console error will not introduce any bad effect to the dialog. We already fixed it internal. You can just ignore this error. Did you check whether office.context.ui.messageParent is null or undefined ? if it is not, then the dialog has been initialized successfully. Then it will be only something wrong with the postMessage method, what system and browser version are you using ? 
1. If it is Win10 and latest version of IE, please make sure the dialog first page domain is same with the taskpane domain. Or you can use other browser to try it.
2. If it is Win7&8&8.1 and IE, then you can just try in other browser to see whether the messageParent api is work. We have already done a code change to fix the IE issue. It will be deployed to prod soon.